# How to get All memcached data in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memcached, express

First, my purpose is when the user close the browser then the user session data should expire. Now the problem is that, my Server requires memcached to work properly. So, I want to delete that specific user session from memcached who has closed his browser. I dont want to clear all memcached so that the remaining users' session should still exist.

Comment: Are you using [`connect-memcached`](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached) for this?  It should already take care of this for you.

Comment: Yes, I am using connect-memcached but the thing is It returns me only the current user key with request.sessionID but I want all users keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Memcached there is no way to list all keys in a specific namespace unless you want to use [some workarounds](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/), and I don't recommend you in production.

One alternative would be to store all user-related Memcached keys in a set (stored in memcached as well). The set key is generated using the user id, so that you always know in advance its value and you can easily retrieve it.

Once the user session ends, you can fetch the item containing the list of user keys, then delete each key. Keep in mind that the key containing the list of keys should have an expiration greater than any item-specific item.

It is also worth mentioning that [Redis](http://redis.io/) supports key iteration and sets by default, and you can configure it to work like Memcached. You may want to give it a try.

Comment: I can't use Redis as The server only handling Memcached and I dont have permission to change the server. Kindly suggest any other workaround of method through which I could be able to get all the keys.

Comment: I already suggested you a method in my answer that doesn't involve changing infrastructure.