# Python: get list of memcached key values by wildcards

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am using `memcached` with `pylibmc` as binaries in my Django app. Now what I want to get list of key values from cache.

Suppose I have this key value pair data in cache,

```
{'Key_1':[1,2,3]} {'Key_2':[4,5,6]} {'Key_3':[6,7,8]}
```

I can get a single record by

```
cache.get('Key_1')
```

I want to get all `Key_*`data

```
cache.get('Key_*')
```

Anyone suggest a way? or is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate. ygneo's answer might be of help to you >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048257/get-list-of-cache-keys-in-django

Comment: Its just for development, they don't recommend it for production.

Comment: what server are you using on production ?

Comment: if you use a mac you could give https://github.com/andrewfromcali/mcinsight a try

Comment: Its not still decided but according to @Simone Carletti' anwser its not good for production. >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956781/534790

Comment: why would you want to do it in production anyways ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have dictionary than you can do something like this:

```
import re
dict = { 'Key_1':[1,2,3], 'Key_2':[4,5,6], 'Key_3':[6,7,8] }
r = re.compile(r"Key_\d+")   // matching expression
matching_keys = filter(r.match, dict.keys())
```

This way you can get all matching keys and then simply iterate on those keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the `mcdict` library and iterate through memcached like a normal dictionary or else you could look at the [`mcdict` source code](https://github.com/wavetossed/mcdict) and apply the same technique in your own code.